# Bluemix - BXNUI0005E: The application could not be added

Tags: ibm-cloud

Since today, when creating an app (Web or Mobile), Bluemix prompts an error :

```
BXNUI0005E: The application could not be added.
```

Anyone else is facing this issue?

Comment: Same problem here with a fresh account.

Comment: Please see answer from Steve Coates below, you are probably entering an application name that is already taken. Bluemix will use the app name to create the route (URL), so it needs to be unique.

Comment: im having the same issue (same error id BXNUI0005E) trying to create an IOT cloud foundry app, and the reason was a issue with the service "Internet of Things Platform" in EEUU South region, so in the erro message check the status page just in case :)

Answer (score 4):

I'm new to Bluemix and just had this error when running through my first tutorial. I fixed it by changing my application name to something that should be unique rather than the 'HelloWorld' I had been trying.

Comment: this worked for me, to have a unique name you can samply name it as: (you user name)+(a name for the app) ..in my case meccharefApp1

Answer (score 1):

If you are using a 'lite' plan, you can create only ONE Cloud foundry app. The naming convention (dns or App) has nothing to do with it.

I was pulling my hair checking for any duplicates in the apps name. Hope this helps for any noobs looking for an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Today testing the app creation either with "web" or with "Mobile" gives no error.
This problem might be caused by having hit the personal account limit of App/Services or a temporary outage of App/Services itself.

Answer (score 0):

You have to choose a unique application name.

Answer (score 0):

Normally, the problem occurs when the app name exists already. The simple way to check by;
    .mybluemix.net
    .eu-gb.mybluemix.net
    .aus-syd.mybluemix.net

Answer (score 0):

I've had this exact same problem and it turned out to be due to previous app implementation as jningthou mentioned above, however in my case, it turned out not to be the old app (which I had deleted) but a database instance (which my previous app had also created).

Deleting hangover app / database instances made the problem go away for me.

Answer (score 0):

Go back to Dashboard and delete everything there.